# Patching a class imported with import function

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to patch a class imported with the `__import__` function but don't get it to work.

```py
class Bar():
  def __init__(self, class_name)
    obj = getattr(__import__(class_name, fromlist=[class_name]), class_name)()

class TestBoard(unittest.TestCase):
  @patch('MyClass', autospec=True)
  def test_serial_construction(self, class_mock):
    Bar('MyClass')
```

The class is not mocked but when I replace the `__import__` with a real object construction it does work:

```
class Bar():
  def __init__(self, class_name)
    obj = MyClass()
```

How can I get it to work with `__import__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate your line into a seperate `set_object` method and then you can easily just patch that method to replace it with a different method

```
def set_object(self):
     self.obj = getattr(__import__(class_name, fromlist=[class_name]), class_name)()
```

```
new_method = lambda self: self.obj = 'I didnt import this'
with patch('myclass.set_object', new_method):
```

Comment: Works nice! Thx!